# Cannot discover Android device

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, usb

I have made a simple Android Application and have chosen to debug it on my android mobile. On connecting it with the PC and enabling USB debugging on mobile, the Android Device Chooser is not showing the mobile.

Comment: which device are you connecting (make,model)

Comment: It could be a multitude of things, but the one that keeps catching me out is that if the phone's display is locked, that'll frequently lock out lots of USB functions too.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the phone driver

example:

samsung need kies http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/

for nexus device just use google usb driver http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Answer (score 1):

On my nexus5 I need to turn on Camera (PTP) storage mode as well as Debugging before the device appears in DDMS.
Settings -> Storage -> Options (top right) -> USB computer connection then select Camera (PTP).

Answer (score 0):

Use [adb driver](http://adbdriver.com/). From my experience, this small - free software works for all vendors and devices.

Comment: Do you mean the software? Check this http://adbdriver.com/documentations/how-to-use-android-adb-driver-installer-for-windows-xp-vista-7-8.html Its working on windows 8